# Game design + reconciling functions across scenes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, gamekit

I've been reading about compartmentalizing functions to be used in a game, which I'm making (using entity component design). My question has to do with how to implement this.

This game makes use of multiple scenes. Across these scenes, I'm finding I've written code that is doing largely the same thing multiple times (e.g. a code to animate a character).

So I see something like this:

```
func animateCharacter() {

}
```

...multiple times across various files associated with each scene.

What is the correct way to write a function once within a scene, and then share it across the other scenes? Is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this problem was sorted when I implemented GameKit correctly (e.g. using one view controller across multiple scenes). Someone in an earlier comment helped me do this, after which time I made all other scenes subclasses of an initial scene, and used the function in the original class.

Answer (score 0):

If the `animateCharacter` function animates a particular node, you can include it in that node's subclass.

```
class CharacterNode: SCNNode {
    func animateCharacter() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then no matter which scene you are in, you can call this method on the node.

```
myCharacterNode.animateCharacter()
```

If you want to share this behavior between multiple different node subclasses, you can use protocols. (You can also use traditional inheritance with all animatable nodes inheriting from some superclass, but you mentioned you wanted to use an entity-component design instead.)

First declare the protocol which defines the methods and properties to share.

```
protocol Animatable {
    func animateCharacter()
}
```

Then in an extension you can provide a default implementation:

```
extension Animatable where Self: SCNNode {
    func animateCharacter() {
        // default implementation here
    }
}
```

To make your objects conform to this protocol and adopt this behavior, add their conformance in an extension.

```
extension CharacterNode: Animatable {}
extension OtherCharacterNode: Animatable {}
```

Comment: I'm trying to share it between SKScene files (as in different files that manage the code for various scenes).

Comment: A good practice is to try to get code out of your scenes and into more specific objects. If your code is currently at the scene level, there is probably a way to refactor it out. If it needs to be at the scene level for some reason, you can just create a scene subclass that implements the function, and have all other scenes inherit from that scene.